# The 'total' field of /comments result is showing up as 0.

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Running the following query:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/comments

Yields:

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "comments": [
  ...
```

Notice that the `total` entry indicates there are *0 comments on all of StackOverflow!* I know that this can't be right, because the `comments` array has 30 items in it.

Comment: I guess it's 'bug report day' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 5.5 million of SO's comments are now being reported.  Silly bug that one.